# Prove that $f( \limsup \limits_{x \to +\infty} x_n)$ = $ \limsup \limits_{x \to +\infty} f(x_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

The problem is divided into two questions:

$x_n$ is a real valued sequence.

- Prove that $f( \limsup \limits_{n \to +\infty} x_n)$ = $ \limsup \limits_{n \to +\infty} f(x_n)$ given that $f$ is continuous and increasing.
- What can we say when $f$ is decreasing.

If it were a regular limit I can just pass the $\lim$ inside the function and we're done. But this is $\limsup$ .

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

For any sequence $(y_{n})$ let $y_{n}^{+} = \sup_{k\geq n}y_{k}$. Let $L = \limsup x_{n}$ be a real number. Since $L = \lim x_{n}^{+}$ and $f$ is continuous, we have $$f(L) = \lim f(x_{n}^{+}).$$ Now we show that $f(x_{n}^{+}) = f(x_{n})^{+}$ for each $n$. Since $x_{n}^{+}\geq x_{k}$ for each $k\geq n$ and  $f$ is increasing, we have $f(x_{n}^{+})\geq f(x_{n})^{+}$. For any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $k\geq n$ such that $x_{n}^{+}-\varepsilon < x_{k}$. Again using the fact that $f$ is increasing we get $f(x_{n}^{+}-\varepsilon)\leq f(x_{k})\leq f(x_{n})^{+}$. Letting $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$ and using the continuity of $f$ we get $f(x_{n}^{+})\leq f(x_{n})^{+}$.

If $f$ is decreasing then $(-f)$ is increasing and thus $(-f)(\limsup x_{n}) = \limsup\:(-f)(x_{n})$. This reduces to $f(\limsup x_{n}) = \liminf f(x_{n})$ after simplification.